# Access drone footage over WiFi

Tags: video-transmitters, fpv-cameras

I have a drone (E520S) which transmits its video footage over WiFi to an app (eachine pro) and I was wondering if I could view the footage without using the app or learn how it is transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

Highly unlikely. The app is made by the producer of the drone, and they have a vested interest in keeping you using their app. And for a third party to go to the trouble of cracking the encoding for each Eachine drone model is unlikely.

Probably if you actually need to get the raw data you will have to flash custom firmware onto the drone itself, something along the lines of [this blog post](https://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/open-source-firmware-for-toy-drones).

I guess it depends how much effort you're willing to put into it, but unless you've got a really good reason to intercept the signal, it's probably best to stick with the official software.